# VS 2015 + vNext + Azure: Publish works, but SCM deploy doesn't?

Tags: azure, deployment, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

### Background

Working on an ASP.NET vNext/5 web site that I'd like to deploy to Azure.

The site is static HTML with the exception of a middleware in `IApplicationBuilder` that serves .less files as text/css.

### Problem

When I deploy via publish from Visual Studio, my site shows up as I expect in Azure.

When I commit via Bitbucks and the SCM management tool picks it up, it appears to work correctly (no errors or warnings in the logs), but on the page, I see:

[image]

### Logs (for reference)

The deployment script generation log:

```
Using cached version of deployment script (command: 'azure -y --no-dot-deployment -r "D:\home\site\repository" -o "D:\home\site\deployments\tools" --aspNet5 "D:\home\site\repository\src\app\JanelSipala.Web2\project.json"').
```

The deployment log itself:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET 5 Web Application deployment.
KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1 already installed.
Adding D:\local\UserProfile\.kre\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin to process PATH
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\app\JanelSipala.Web2\project.json
Resolving complete, 653ms elapsed
Restore complete, 669ms elapsed
Copying to output path D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS.nuspec
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.Interop 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.Interop\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.Interop\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.Interop.nuspec
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Http 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.AspNet.Http.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Logging 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.Framework.Logging\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.Framework.Logging\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.Framework.Logging.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.Framework.Logging.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Interfaces 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Interfaces\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Interfaces\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Interfaces.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Interfaces.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.FileSystems 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.FileSystems\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.FileSystems\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.AspNet.FileSystems.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.AspNet.FileSystems.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.PipelineCore 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.PipelineCore\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.PipelineCore\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.AspNet.PipelineCore.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.AspNet.PipelineCore.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.Framework.OptionsModel.dll
 Using Package dependency Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.6
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Newtonsoft.Json\6.0.6
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Newtonsoft.Json\6.0.6
    File: Newtonsoft.Json.nuspec
    File: lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.FileSystems.Interfaces 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.FileSystems.Interfaces\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.FileSystems.Interfaces\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.AspNet.FileSystems.Interfaces.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.AspNet.FileSystems.Interfaces.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.FeatureModel 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.FeatureModel\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.FeatureModel\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.AspNet.FeatureModel.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.AspNet.FeatureModel.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.HttpFeature 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.HttpFeature\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.HttpFeature\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.AspNet.HttpFeature.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.AspNet.HttpFeature.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities.dll
 Using Package dependency Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Interfaces 1.0.0-beta2
  Copying files for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
    Source: D:\local\UserProfile\.kpm\packages\Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Interfaces\1.0.0-beta2
    Target: D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\packages\Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Interfaces\1.0.0-beta2
    File: Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Interfaces.nuspec
    File: lib\aspnet50\Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Interfaces.dll
 Using Project dependency JanelSipala.Web2 1.0.0 for Asp.Net,Version=v5.0
  Copying source code from Project dependency JanelSipala.Web2
    Source D:\home\site\repository\src\app\JanelSipala.Web2\project.json
    Target D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\approot\src\JanelSipala.Web2
 Packing runtime KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1
Copying contents of Project dependency JanelSipala.Web2 to D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\wwwroot
  Source D:\home\site\repository\src\app\JanelSipala.Web2\wwwroot
  Target D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9\wwwroot
Time elapsed 00:00:12.6399350
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\local\Temp\8969a71d-4e0c-4748-ba17-0ab37477e0d9' to: 'D:\home\site'
Copying file: 'approot\global.json'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1.nupkg'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1.nupkg.sha512'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\KRE-CLR-x86.nuspec'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\k.cmd'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\klr.cmd'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\klr.exe'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\klr.host.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\klr.net45.config'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\klr.net45.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\klr.net45.managed.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\kpm.cmd'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Desktop.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Desktop.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\lib\Microsoft.Framework.DesignTimeHost\Microsoft.Framework.DesignTimeHost.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\lib\Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager\Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\packages\KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1\bin\lib\Microsoft.Framework.Project\Microsoft.Framework.Project.dll'
Copying file: 'approot\src\JanelSipala.Web2\project.json'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\web.config'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\assets\css\sb-admin-2.css'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\assets\css\site.css'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\assets\css\timeline.css'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\assets\js\flot-data.js'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\assets\js\morris-data.js'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\angular\angular.js'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\angular-mocks\angular-mocks.js'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\angular-route\angular-route.js'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\bootstrap.css'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\bootstrap.js'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\bootstrap.less'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\bootstrap-social\bootstrap-social.css'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\datatables\jquery.dataTables.css'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\datatables\jquery.dataTables.js'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\datatables-plugins\.bower.json'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\datatables-plugins\make.sh'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\datatables-plugins\README.md'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\datatables-plugins\api\average().js'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\datatables-plugins\api\column().title().js'
Copying file: 'wwwroot\lib\datatables-plugins\api\columns().order().js'
Omitting next output lines...
Finished successfully.
```

Comment: One thing I noticed (in case it helps) -- it appears that it's attempting to build using KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-beta1, but I specifically am using beta2 locally. Not sure how it's set to beta1 on Azure -- wondering if I can configure it, or if I just have to wait for them to move to beta2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in this case, the solution is to move everything back to beta1.

In the project application settings:

[image]

And in the `project.json` file:

[image]

Once I did that, Azure deployment from SCM worked just fine.